# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_create_unverified_context'

Tags: python, ssl

I got the following error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_create_unverified_context'.

I'm using Python 3.4.2 .

**My code:**

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

When I run this code, the error happens.`_create_unverified_context` can be used in Python 3.4.2, so I really cannot understand why this error happens. How should I fix this?
Traceback says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 3, in <module>
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_create_unverified_context'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure _create_verified_context is an attribute and not a method? Have you tried:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
```

Comment: Actually, I do not think so. You cannot have the same error so please post you error.

Comment: I added my full traceback

Comment: Even if it is a method why would you call it? Also `ssl` is a module not a class.

Comment: My bad, I was not checking that you are using Python3.4. As far as I know, _create_unverified_context exists in Python3.6 but is not supported in Python3.4. You can check yourself by looking at Lib\ssl.py.

Comment: @t.m.adam So,how should I fix this?

Comment: Upgrade to Python3.6 and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs if:

- python version is less than 2.7 i
- if the module being used isn't compatible with the python version being used

  Faced same issue when using module "pysphere" with python 2.7.3.

Just commenting out the line "ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context()" in the piece of code i had, worked.