# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, google-sheets, ssl, google-cloud-platform

I used a python package called python-certifi-win32 to fix this issue, but when I make an executable and run the file I am getting this error again. I also referred from another post and directly imported certifi-win32 package into my program and it worked except I am getting the same error in another part of my project.

This is the fix I got from another post.

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import certifi_win32
    os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certifi_win32.wincerts.where()
    certifi_win32.generate_pem()
```

This is the error I am getting right now after trying all the fixes.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
  File "customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "src\app\frontend\main_ui.py", line 51, in run_orm_google_sheets
    status = orm.run_google_sheets_save(drive_folder_id)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src\app\backend\oscilloscope_report_maker.py", line 219, in run_google_sheets_save
    spreadsheet_id = gs.create("Report")
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src\app\backend\google_sheets_api_methods.py", line 41, in create
    .execute()
     ^^^^^^^^^
  File "googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
  File "googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
  File "googleapiclient\http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
  File "googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
  File "google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
  File "httplib2\__init__.py", line 1724, in request
  File "httplib2\__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
  File "httplib2\__init__.py", line 1366, in _conn_request
  File "httplib2\__init__.py", line 1158, in connect
  File "ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1002)
```

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries. If the provided information was helpful,you can check this link. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: Hey, sorry for not replying. It didn't really work. It says there is an AttributeError but I don't really have any file names same as 'ssl' to create an issue of circular import. I lost as to why it isn't working.

Comment: Do checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390968/) it can be helpful in resolving your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the github [link](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32):

`Python-certifi-win32` package has been replaced by `pip-system-certs` and is generally unmaintained.

To fix your issue you can also try importing SSL by running the below command:

```
import ssl 
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

To read your link content, you can use:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(urllink)
```

Comment: Oh alright, thank you for pointing it out, ill try them out and let you know if it worked out.

Comment: I am getting this error when I try to package the project: `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'ssl' has no attribute '_create_unverified_context' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Comment: Refer to this SO [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762996/how-to-fix-attributeerror-partially-initialized-module) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882773/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-create-unverified-context). Let me know if this helps.